# Estimate of compact operator, using one-to-one bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X, Y, Z$ be Banach spaces, $K ∈ K(X, Y )$, and let $J ∈ B(Y, Z)$ be one-to-one. Show that
for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a constant $C_\epsilon > 0$ such that
$|Kx| \leq \epsilon|x| + C_\epsilon|JKx|, x ∈ X.$

I have been trying to prove this for a while, but every attempt so far has lead to a dead end. Could anyone give a hint where to start?